# Asynctask not working on SDK 23 or before

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Good day,
for what the problem I met now, my asynctask is working for SDK 24 or above,but when I put it on SDK 21,22,23 emulator and real devices, it doen't work.

The weird thing is:
1.) Asynctasks on my first activity and fragment are working, but the 2nd activity's asysntask is not working,error code: 400, exception java.lang.IllegalStateException : myURL.

My asynctask with doInBackGround code:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    //creating a URL
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    //Opening the URL using HttpURLConnection
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    //StringBuilder object to read the string from the service
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    //We will use a buffered reader to read the string from service
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    //A simple string to read values from each line
                    String json;

                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (!json.contains("<br")) {
                            sb.append(json + "\n");
                        }
                    }

                    //finally returning the read string
                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
        }
    }
```

For this code, works on SDK 24,25,26. and it will throw an exception at con.getInputStream(). I am not sure what is the problem. Is it thread or what other problems? Thanks.

```
IOExeption
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:mrURL
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at com.example.reonyx.tracking5.PlayBackActivity$1GetJSON.doInBackground(PlayBackActivity.java:1206)
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at com.example.reonyx.tracking5.PlayBackActivity$1GetJSON.doInBackground(PlayBackActivity.java:964)
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-27 02:28:29.453 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-27 02:28:29.454 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-27 02:28:29.454 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-27 02:28:29.454 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-27 02:28:29.454 16954-17698/com.example.reonyx.tracking5 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Anytime you have an exception and you're trying to figure out the reason why, you should add the stack trace to the question. The stack trace usually tells you what the problem is. If not, the stack trace will give us more information to help you with. Also, consider using `Log.e` instead of `System.out.println` for logging errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is it aynctask not working or HttpURLConnection is not working as expected ? I can understand as per code you are using the get url to retrive the data.

I can suggest to use getResponseCode method to wait for the response and then try to use getInputStream method.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(strings[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

          // use bufferreder to get the data from input stream.

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       if(urlConnection!=null)
         urlConnection.disconnect();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but it isn't an answer. When you get more reputation you can add clarification comments to the original post. If the OP adds clarification, update your answer with something more concrete. ;)

Comment: Response code is 400 as I mentioned before. Everything works on SDK 24 or above, only SDK 23 or below are not working.